# Should pans be washed before adding more poultry?

Tags: food-safety, poultry

In a bakery kitchen should the pans used to hold the raw chicken be washed before placing more raw chicken in those same pans? Especially if there are hours between usage.

Answer (score 11):

IMO, in a professional/commercial kitchen you should never re-use and always use clean equipment.

The risk of contamination is great(er) in case of chicken, so is the risk of having an inspector coming in and seeing dirty equipment lying around.

Comment: The key information is "hours between usage". Placing raw chicken in a container, then putting more in a half an hour later, is no cause for concern if it's cooked after that.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of food safety, once a piece of equipment touches a piece of food, the equipment *is that piece of food* until it's been properly cleaned. If you put a piece of raw chicken in a pan, then take it out and wait several hours, that pan is still chicken that's been unrefrigerated longer than it should've been.